# String Encoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

I recently started working with encoding in Ruby, and am confused by some behavior.

I'm using 2.2.3p173 and am showing the following:

```
__ENCODING__             #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>  Default encoding in 2.2.3

"my_string".encoding     #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Object.to_s.encoding     #=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
Object.new.to_s.encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

What's the cause of this discrepancy in encodings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice find!

The short answer is it's completely arbitrary and it depends on how Ruby internally builds the strings that are being returned.

There are a whole host of internal C functions that construct empty strings or literal strings with US-ASCII encoding: [`rb_usascii_str_new`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L1212) and similar. They're frequently used to construct strings by appending smaller fragments of strings. Almost every `to_s` method does this:

```
[].to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
{}.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
$/.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
1.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
true.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
Object.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

So why not `Object.new.to_s`? The key here is that `Object#to_s` is the fallback `to_s` method for *every* class, so in order to make it generic-yet-informative they coded it to output the value of the object's internal pointer. The easiest way to do that is with `sprintf` and the `%p` specifier. *BUT* whoever coded Ruby's `sprintf` wrapper `rb_sprintf` got lazy and just set the encoding to [`NULL`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/sprintf.c#L1442) which falls back to `ASCII-8BIT`. So generally anything that returns a formatted string will have this encoding:

```
Object.new.to_s
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
nil.sort rescue $!.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
[].each.to_s.encoding
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

As for strings defined by a script, those get the default encoding UTF-8 as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is defined in [C](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c)
if you try the following:

```
String(123456).encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
"123456".encoding       #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

I did not dig a lot in ruby source code but it [looks](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?p=2&q=rb_usascii_str_new2%28&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) like is harcoded the encoding (`rb_usascii_str_new2`) for `to_s`